# Returning Server Side Data Wrapped in a Fiber to a Client Side Call with MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to get the server side method to return the tweet JSON objects in the browser console. So far my app can pull information from the Twitter API and insert all of that data into a Collection but it won't return data to the call. I've done a bunch of tests with calls and methods to debug this issue and I think the Fiber might change how this call/method works.

http://sf-tweet-locator.meteor.com/

I want to be able to pull the longetude and latitude from each object so that I can place pins of the location of each tweet on a map. I'm not sure if the way that I am doing it is the "best" way but I am open to all suggestions!

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.call("tweets", function(error, results) {
    console.log(results); //results.data should be a JSON object
  });
}

Meteor.methods({
  Fiber = Npm.require('fibers');

  tweets: function(){
    Twit = new TwitMaker({
      consumer_key: '...',
      consumer_secret: '...',
      access_token: '...',
      access_token_secret: '...'
    });

    sanFrancisco = [ '-122.75', '36.8', '-121.75', '37.8' ];

    stream = Twit.stream('statuses/filter', { locations: sanFrancisco });

    var wrappedInsert = Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(tweet) {
      var userName = tweet.user.screen_name;
      var userTweet = tweet.text;
      console.log(userName + " says: " + userTweet);
      Posts.insert(tweet);
      return tweet;

    }, "Failed to insert tweet into Posts collection.");

    stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
      wrappedInsert(tweet);
      return tweet;
    });
  }, 
})
```

Comment: How would you want to do this, you're using the stream API so some tweets may come in slightly later. You can only return to the call once. Which of the tweets do you want to get a return on, what it be the first tweet?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it as a publication - that way you're not inserting useless data into your `Posts` collection,

This example creates a publication, which sends each new tweet to the `local-tweets` collection on the client.

You could possibly pass a `queryId` to the subscription/publication, and return that in each tweet document if you need to reference the source query.

```
if (Meteor.isClient){
  var localTweets = new Meteor.Collection('local-tweets');

  Meteor.subscribe("tweets", [ '-122.75', '36.8', '-121.75', '37.8' ]);

  localTweets.observe({
    added: function(doc) { console.log('tweet received!', doc); }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer){
  Meteor.publish("tweets", function(bbox){
    var pub = this, stopped = false;
    var Twit = new TwitMaker({
      consumer_key: '...',
      consumer_secret: '...',
      access_token: '...',
      access_token_secret: '...'
    });
    stream = Twit.stream('statuses/filter', { locations: bbox });

    var publishTweet = Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(tweet) {
      if (stopped) return;
      pub.added("local-tweets", Random.id() /* or some other id*/, tweet);
    }, "Failed to tweet.");

    stream.on('tweet', publishTweet);

    this.ready()

    this.onStop(function(){
      /* any other cleanup? */
      stopped = true;
    });
  });

}
```